# Browserstack reports successful even when test fails in Nightwatchjs

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I just started using nightwatch with browserstack and I'm noticing that when we get a failed test, nightwatch registers the failure, but browserstack does not. 
[sample test I am using](https://github.com/browserstack/automate-node-samples/tree/master/nightwatch). 
Also I am using free trial version of BrowserStack.

My question is:

1. Are there any ideas how to tell browserstack when a test run failed ?

From BrowserStack [doc](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node):

> REST API
>
> It is possible to mark tests as either a pass or a fail, using the
>   following snippet:

```
var request = require("request"); 
request({
    uri: "https://user:key@www.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/<session-id>.json",
    method: "PUT",
    form: {
        "status": "completed",
        "reason":""
    }
});
```

> The two
>   potential values for status can either be completed or error.
>   Optionally, a reason can also be passed.

My questions are:

2. How I can get 'session-id' after test execution ?
3. What if I can see "completed" status in dashboard already ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. A session on BrowserStack has only three types of statuses: 
   **Completed**, **Error** or **Timeout**. Selenium (and hence, BrowserStack) does not have a way of understanding, if a test has passed or failed. Its by the multiple assertions in your tests that appear on your console, that you infer if a test has passed / failed. These assertions however, do not reach BrowserStack. As you rightly identified, you can use the [REST-API](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/rest-api), to change the status of the session to 'Error', if you see a failure in your console.
2. I would suggest fetching the session ID of the test as the test is being executed, since fetching the session ID **after** the test execution is a lengthy process. In Nightwatch, you can fetch session ID as follows:

```js
browser.session(function(session) {
    console.log(session.sessionId);
});
```

3. Yes, you can certainly change the status of the session once it is completed. That's where the REST-API comes to help!

Comment: Is there an easier way to force fail the test at BrowserStack? Instead of having to meddle with the API, figuring out the build and session ID...

Comment: You can mark the session as "Error" only via REST-API.
There is no other approach. That said, you don't need the build ID to change the status of a session, only the session ID is enough. Check this link for more details - https://www.browserstack.com/automate/rest-api#rest-api-sessions

Comment: Their support told me that I could do `driver.getSessionId()` to get the id right away.

Comment: Depends on what language you are using. If you are using Nightwatch, you can use the method shared above. For Java, it is `driver.getSessionId()` to get the session ID.

Answer (score 1):

If you came here searching for a solution in Python, you could use

```
requests.put(
    "https://api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/{}.json".format(driver.session_id),
    auth=(USERNAME, ACCESS_KEY),
    json={"status": "failed", "reason": "test failed"})
```